# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to make a quiz web app and whenever I added map function in my `QuestionBox.js` it throus a error.

Does anyone have solution for this problem ?

Error :

```
   4 | const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(options);
   5 | return (
   6 |   <div className="questionBox">
>  7 |     <div className="question">{question}</div>
     | ^   8 |     {answer.map((text, index) => (
   9 |       <button
  10 |         key={index}
```

Code of `QuestionBox.js` :

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const QuestionBox = ({question, options, selected}) => {
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(options);
  return (
    <div className="questionBox">
      <div className="question">{question}</div>
      {answer.map((text, index) => (
        <button
          key={index}
          className="answerBtn"
          onClick={() => {
            setAnswer([text]);
            selected(text);
          }}
        >
          {text}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default QuestionBox;
```

Comment: show us the way you are sending the props to the QuestionBox Component

Comment: {this.state.questionBank.length > 0 && this.state.questionBank.map(
           ({question,answer,correct,questionId}) => (
             <QuestionBox 
               question={question}
               options={answer}
               key={questionId}
             />

           )
           ) }

Comment: Now, we need to know how the questionBank object would look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{this.state.questionBank.length > 0 && this.state.questionBank.map( ({question,answer,correct,questionId}) => (  ) ) } –

here the answer should be answers as defined in the QuizService

here is the correct QuestionBox props

{this.state.questionBank.length > 0 && this.state.questionBank.map( ({question,answers,correct,questionId}) => (  ) ) } –

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because `options` is undefined when`QuestionBox` is rendered. You should try this:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

const QuestionBox = ({question, options = [], selected}) => {
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(options);
  return (
    <div className="questionBox">
      <div className="question">{question}</div>
      {answer && answer.map((text, index) => (
        <button
          key={index}
          className="answerBtn"
          onClick={() => {
            setAnswer([text]);
            selected(text);
          }}
        >
          {text}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default QuestionBox;
```

Comment: yes the type error is gone but the buttons are not appeared . can you tell whats wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Assign default empty array to the `question` argument. It will solve the issue as for the first time it might be undefined.